# API endpoint has special character "|" that cannot be escaped in perl?

Tags: perl

Trying to send an API to update a form. The URI contains the character "`|`" at then end.
It looks something like

```
HOST/API/V1/entry/formid|formid
```

I'm using Perl and using the REST::Client to build the API.
I have tried using uri_unescape so that the system doesn't translate the "`|`" character but it seems like the REST::Client will still translate it to "`%7C`" every time which will result in a 404. Is this a limitation to the REST::Client package?

Does anyone know another way to stop the system from translating the special character?

Comment: Re "*Is this a limitation to the REST::CLIENT package?*", No, this is a bug on the server side. It should accept `%7C` to mean `|` in URLs

Comment: `|` is not in the unreserved character set specified by RFC3986, and therefore must be percent-encoded when part of a URI.

Comment: REST::Client has many other problems. I've tried it several times from various projects, but it doesn't really add any value over bare LWP. It was recently updated, but only to make it installable and change its build system.